# Flutter: _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) When it should not be possible

Tags: android, ios, flutter, function

I have a a list of checkbox tiles that worked for a long time and then I started messing with it due to an error and now all of my TaskList widgets are broken. The Tasklist widget is composed of a bunch of checkbox tiles. Unfortunately after messing with it I can no longer check the checkboxes because they throw a "_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)" when attempting to call my VoidCallBack updatePercentComplete(). In my opinion this function should never be able to be null however it ends up being null. Is there any way to fix this?

Thank You!!!

main:

```
 void updatePercentComplete() {
    saveData();
    int count = 0;
    for (Task task in _todayTasks) {
      if (task.isComplete) {
        count += 1;
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      if (_todayTasks.isEmpty) {
        dailyProgress = 0;
      } else {
        dailyProgress = count / _todayTasks.length;
      }
    });

    if (dailyProgress == 1) {
      _controllerTopCenter.play();
    }
  }

...

return TasksPage(
                    passedTaskList: _userTaskList,
                    deleteTask: deleteTask,
                    startAddNewTask: startAddNewTask,
                    updatePercentComplete: updatePercentComplete,
                  );
```

TaskPage:

```
  final List<Task> passedTaskList;
  final Function deleteTask;
  final Function startAddNewTask;
  final VoidCallback updatePercentComplete;

  const TasksPage(
      {required this.passedTaskList,
      required this.deleteTask,
      required this.startAddNewTask,
      required this.updatePercentComplete,
      super.key});
...

body: TaskList(
             _laterTasks,
             widget.deleteTask,
             widget.updatePercentComplete,
)
```

TaskList:

```
return DismissableTask(

  final List<Task> _passedTaskList;
  final Function deleteTask;
  final VoidCallback? updatePercentComplete;

  const TaskList(
      this._passedTaskList, this.deleteTask, Function getPercentComplete,
      {this.updatePercentComplete, super.key});
...

       return DismissableTask(
                    getPercentComplete: updatePercentComplete,
                    passedTaskList: _passedTaskList,
                    deleteTask: deleteTask,
                    index: index,
                  );
```

DismissableTask:

```
  final List<Task> passedTaskList;
  final int index;
  final Function deleteTask;
  final VoidCallback? getPercentComplete;

  const DismissableTask(
      {required this.passedTaskList,
      required this.index,
      required this.deleteTask,
      required this.getPercentComplete,
      super.key});
...

child: TaskCheckBoxTile(
                thisTaskList: passedTaskList,
                index: index,
                getPercentComplete: getPercentComplete,
```

TaskCheckBoxTile:

```
final List<Task> thisTaskList;
  final int index;
  final VoidCallback? getPercentComplete;

  const TaskCheckBoxTile(
      {required this.thisTaskList,
      required this.index,
      required this.getPercentComplete,
      super.key});

return CheckboxListTile(
      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
      activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 56, 81),
      value: widget.thisTaskList[widget.index].isComplete,
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() {
          widget.thisTaskList[widget.index].isComplete = val ?? false;
          //This is where the error is thrown
          **widget.getPercentComplete!();**
        });
      },
```

Comment: Your `TaskList` constructor takes *two* callback arguments: a *positional* `getPercentComplete` callback and an optional, *named* `updatePercentComplete` callback.  It uses `updatePercentComplete` when constructing a `DismissableTask`, but it seems to completely ignore the `getPercentComplete` callback.  Meanwhile `TaskPage` passes a callback only for that ignored positional parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Jamesdlin is correct. I had an extra parameter.

Comment: This looks like a comment, not an answer.